# Rename every column of df with a part of their filename - R

Tags: r

I have files with the naming convention and all the same column names:

```
ABC_file_name_25
ABC_file_name_50
ABC_file_name_100
```

I want each `df` to have their column names represent which file they are from. So right now all `df` have:

```
col1    col2     col3
```

And I want them to be:

df1

```
col1_ABC_25    col2_ABC_25    col3_ABC_25
```

df2

```
col1_ABC_50    col2_ABC_50    col3_ABC_50
```

df3

```
col1_ABC_100    col2_ABC_100    col3_ABC_100
```

So far I have this, but I'm not sure how to apply the names to the columns:

```
library(tools)

# Working Directory
setwd("C:/.../Files")

# Get a list of files to read in
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
# Remove .csv
file_name = file_path_sans_ext(temp)
# Get the start of filename prefix 
prefix = sub("_.*", "", file_name[1:1])
# Get the suffix number
suffix = sub(".*_", "", file_name)

# Name each df by its filename
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(file_path_sans_ext(temp[i]), read.csv(temp[i]))
# Place all df into a list using their prefix
list <- lapply(ls(pattern=prefix), function(x) get(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load each file as a data frame, change the column names as desired, and then collect them into a list.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

all_files <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
    file <- read.csv(x)
    # Get the start of filename prefix 
    prefix = sub("_.*", "", x)
    # Get the suffix number
    suffix = sub(".*_", "", x)

    colnames(file) <- paste(colnames(file), prefix, suffix, sep='_')
    return(file)
}
```